# AutomicReference compareAndSet usage

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I have this class containing AccessTokenWithExpirationDate object wrapped in AutomicReference which I want it to be thread safe:

```
public class MyClass {

    private AtomicReference<AccessTokenWithExpirationDate> accessTokenWithExpirationDate = new AtomicReference<>();

    private AccessTokenWithExpirationDate putAccessTokenToCache(AccessTokenDto accessTokenDto) {
        AccessTokenWithExpirationDate currentValue = this.accessTokenWithExpirationDate.get();
        AccessTokenWithExpirationDate accessTokenWithExpirationDate
                = new AccessTokenWithExpirationDate(accessTokenDto);
        
        // if currentValue the same, update.
        // if currentValue not the same - another thread already updated it. continue.
        this.accessTokenWithExpirationDate.compareAndSet(currentValue, accessTokenWithExpirationDate);
        
        return accessTokenWithExpirationDate;
    }

    private Optional<String> getAccessTokenFromCache() {
        Optional<AccessTokenWithExpirationDate> accessTokenWithExpirationDate = Optional.ofNullable(this.accessTokenWithExpirationDate.get());
        if (accessTokenWithExpirationDate.isPresent() && isTokenNotExpired(accessTokenWithExpirationDate.get())) {
            return accessTokenWithExpirationDate
                    .map(AccessTokenWithExpirationDate::getTokenDto)
                    .map(AccessTokenDto::getAccessToken);
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

1. lets say AccessTokenWithExpirationDate has initial value and now Thread1 arrives to  method putAccessTokenToCache and run: accessTokenWithExpirationDate.compareAndSet,
   and at the same time other threads try to run:
   accessTokenWithExpirationDate.get() in getAccessTokenFromCache method,
   will all threads calling get() will wait for compareAndSet() to finish to get the value after or not guarantied ?
2. if not, can the class be changed in a way that will allow it? some other use in AutomicReference that can promise that?

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Atomic values don't allow blocking.  In some cases, this is good, but in your case (if understand it correctly), it is not.  As i understand it, you want to cache an access token.  If it doesn't exist yet, or is expired, you want a new token to be created.  Ultimately, you want any caller accessing the cache to get a valid token.

You can achieve this in a performant manner using (the valid form of) double checked locking.

The basic pattern is:

```
private volatile Token _currentToken;

public Token getValidToken() {
  Token token = _currentToken;
  if(!isValidToken(token)) {
    token = loadToken();
  }
  return token;
}

private synchronized Token loadToken() {
  Token token = _currentToken;
  if(!isValidToken(token)) {
    token = // ... get valid token here ...
    _currentToken = token;
  }
  return token;
}

private boolean isValidToken(Token token) {
  // .. validate that token is not null or expired ...
}
```

for callers who call getValidToken() when there is already a valid token, they won't encounter any locking.  note that reading a volatile incurs a similar performance hit without *actually* blocking, but this about the best you can get for concurrent code (without doing something with ThreadLocal and potentially an access token per thread).

for callers who encounter a missing or expired token, they will all block until a single caller gets a new, valid token.

note, there are probably good cache implementations in either google guava or apache commons which would handle this logic for you.

Answer (score 0):

> lets say `AccessTokenWithExpirationDate` has initial value and now Thread1 arrives to method `putAccessTokenToCache()` and run: accessTokenWithExpirationDate.compareAndSet(...), and at the same time other threads try to run: accessTokenWithExpirationDate.get() in getAccessTokenFromCache method, will all threads calling get() will wait for compareAndSet() to finish to get the value after or not guaranteed ?

Whenever `accessTokenWithExpirationDate.get()` is called, the guarantee is that the most recently set value of `accessTokenWithExpirationDate` is returned.  Period.  There is no locking.  If the get is called before the set then the old value is returned.  If the get is called after the set then the new value is returned.

> if not, can the class be changed in a way that will allow it? some other use in AutomicReference that can promise that?

You can certainly add locking but I'm not sure what it buys you.  Either the other threads call `get()` before or after the `set()` has completed.  If you added locking then the same race conditions would happen but you would make the getting and setting of the value a lot more expensive.  In your case, each thread has to cross memory barriers to ensure the correct publishing of the `accessTokenWithExpirationDate` value but there is no blocking.

Full locking is necessary when there are multiple values being updated in an object or if you need to ensure a *single* thread is accessing a resource at a time.  If you need to set a single value, in your case `accessTokenWithExpirationDate`, then an `AtomicReference` is the right tool for the job.